# Center Align Submit button

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, submit

I have a form with a textarea and submit button.
I floated textarea to left and submit button to right.

This is how it is displayed in Firefox.

[image]
This is how it is displayed in IE.

[image]

This is the html code i have written.

```
<div id="form">
  <form method="post" action="google.php">
   <textarea rows="3" cols="40"  style="width: 300px; float: left;"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" style="width: 100px; float: right;" />
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the CSS Code:

```
#form {
 overflow: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 600px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
```

How to align the submit button **vertically** in center with respect to the textarea.?

**ANSWER :** 
I modified the code to meet my requirements.

This is the CSS code :

```
#form {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
  }
 #form  textarea {
   vertical-align: middle;
  }
 #form span{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="form">
    <form method="post" action="google.php">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="40"  style="width: 300px; "></textarea>
    <span><input type="submit" value="Comment"  /></span> </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `display:table` and `display:table-cell`, property. But in this case you have to remove `floats` and give specific width.

**HTML**

```
<div id="form">
  <form method="post" action="google.php">
      <div class='wrap'>
   <textarea rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
      </div>
       <div class='wrap_2'>
<input type="submit"/>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#form{
 overflow: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 600px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 display:table;
}

div.wrap, 
div.wrap_2 {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.wrap {
    width:500px 
}
```

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7gnMu/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `position: absolute` on the submit button, and set it 50% from the top, minus half the height of the button in margin-top.  See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cXSbX/

Answer (score 1):

you can give `margin-left` or `margin-right` property.

ex:

`margin-left:135px;`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the input with some element and text center align the input.

```
<div id="form">
  <form method="post" action="google.php">
   <textarea rows="3" cols="40"  style="width: 300px; float: left;"></textarea>
      <span class="right" style="width: 278px; float: right; text-align:center;"><input type="submit" display:inline-block; /></span>
  </form>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UuFg2/

Comment: sorry..i wanted it to be vertically aligned in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wZs2F/

```
#form {
 overflow: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 600px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.txtinput
{
 margin-left:100px;
}


<div id="form">
  <form method="post" action="google.php">
   <textarea rows="3" cols="40"  style="width: 300px; "></textarea>
      <div class="txtinput">
   <input type="submit" style="width: 100px;"  />
          </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case vertical-align: bottom will not work. Instead height and line-height will make your button to align vertically centered.

Included following styles for input:

```
height: 80px; 
line-height: 70px
```

Have a look at working demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UuFg2/4/)